# One MVC3 Controller method two different ActionResult types?

Tags: design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-3, architecture

Currently I have a Controller, AssetController, that has methods for navigating a tree of assets.

I use this controller to navigate a "gallery" of assets and the controller methods currently return `ViewResult`.

I am starting to build another way of viewing this same data which will make use of ajax and will not want `ViewResult` returned but rather `JsonResult`.

I would like to re-use as much of my controller logic as possible. I can think of two options here:

1. Change all my controller methods to return only `JsonResult` then change my current View to use the json to display the full page.

   **Drawbacks**: This pushes more page loading / redirecting logic onto the client. It also make deep linking a problem I think. With full views the URL's of pages are very "link friendly" in that a user can copy and paste a link and pass it to someone and it will go where they expect. Returning JsonResults mean the URL doesn't change so deep linking becomes more challenging
2. Refactor my current controller so that "shared" code is moved into private methods in the controller. Create new actions that return `JsonResult` and keep existing methods that return ViewResult.

   This is currently my choice as it seems to keep more code in the controller which makes unit testing it easier. But it also seems to be a little too coupled to the UI, what happens when I want to return the data in different formats, do I just keep adding new controller actions with different `ActionResult` types? Is that so bad?

**Is there a smarter way to handle situation or is one of my approaches more favorable than the other?**

**UPDATE**

Here is some code examples to clarify:

Currently I have this:

```
public ActionResult ViewObject(PathModel inPath)
{
    using (engine)
    {
      var metaData = engine.GetFileMetaData(inPath.Path);
  return View(metaData); //This is returning a ViewResult type
    }
}
```

I am thinking about doing something like this

```
private FileMetaDataModel ViewObjectInternal(PathModel inPath)
{               
  using (engine)
  {
      var metaData = engine.GetFileMetaData(inPath.Path);
      return metaData;
  }
}

public ActionResult ViewObjectAsJSON(PathModel inPath)
{
   var jsonResult = new JsonResult();
   jsonResult.Data = ViewObjectInternal(inPath).ToJson();

   return jsonResult // this is returning my data as JSON;
}

public ActionResult ViewObjectAsView(PathModel inPath)
{
  return View(engine.GetFileMetaData(inPath.Path)); //This is returning a ViewResult type
}
```

Comment: Unclear question. Code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just simply return ActionResult?

```
public ActionResult Detail()
{
    // controller logic here

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return Json(model);

    return View(model);    
}
```

Comment: You are returning a ViewResult in your code snippet. you just happen to be casting it as an ActionResult. This is different than way I am asking about

Comment: I'm returning either JsonResult or ViewResult depending on whether request is ajax request or not. It does the same what your code does, except this does it all in one action.

Comment: My mistake didn't notice the early return. I didn't realize there was an IsAjax method on the Request, that is a interesting idea. Will have to think about it a little bit

Comment: This is a good alternative for my exact scenario so I will mark it as the answer. One downside though is if I later expand to support XmlResult (for example) it is dictated by more than just the incoming request properties.

Comment: Actually you could implement more than just IsAjaxRequest. Look at how [IsAjaxRequest](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/66799#338547)is implemented - you could simply create new extension IsXmlRequest and pass custom header or even just url parameter in your ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

well you can set result type as ActionResult. All other results are inherited from it

Answer (score 0):

Option #3 could be use a mix of both. You don't need to use jsonresult 100% of the time. If you are worried though about the urls, you could use a mix of the both.
You have your main view which then dynamically loads each result with jQuery. This is often a better fit for applications with multiple pieces of data - so the perception is the app is loading faster (main view returns followed by bound data) - so you could surely go that route as well understanding that search engines won't index your returned data. Im assuming here your applications data though wouldnt be indexed. If it will - then jsonresult is not the way to go here.

Comment: I don't understand how your explanation is different from my Option 1? It sounds like you are suggesting I move the logic to the view to decide what to do with the controller result?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your concern is in changing your code over from ViewResult to exclusively a JsonResult I believe. In that case, why not use a mixture of both. NOT in the same controller but refactor your code to have a main view load the data for each page. Maybe thats what you meant by option 1 - but it wasnt clear by saying you were going to convert _all_ controllers to jsonresult. The option I'm saying is use some controllers as ViewResult for your views,and your main views all use a ViewResult. We may be saying the same thing - if so - thats the idea.if not thats option 3 :)

Comment: Ok I see, yeah we are saying the same thing. You are actually describing my second option where I support both ViewResult and JsonResult from controller methods. Thanks for the input

Comment: to clarify - I dont mean in the same controller method - just to make sure we're on the same page.